# Print Screen on Windows 7 with Apple keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to identify the `Print Screen` functionality with an Apple keyboard (A1243, 109 keys) on Windows 7. I do not want to use the on-screen keyboard as suggested (and chosen as the accepted answer) in [this duplicate question](https://superuser.com/questions/355503/windows-print-screen-with-mac-keyboard).

I would like to achieve the functionality with key strokes only. If I need to map keys, I would like to achieve this without additional software. What are my options?

I have tried the following key strokes and they definitely do not work on my system: `F13`, `F14`, `F15`, `command+shift+4`, `option+F13`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Keyboard remapping

Quoting Wikipedia:

> A **scancode** (or **scan code**) is the data that most computer keyboards
>   send to a computer to report which keys have been pressed. A number,
>   or sequence of numbers, is assigned to each key on the keyboard.

Since Windows 2000, the `Scancode Map` registry value can be used to remap a key to another or disable it entirely. The scan code mappings are stored in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
```

> In the `Keyboard Layout` key, the `Scancode Map` value must be added. This value is of type `REG_BINARY` (little Endian format) and has the data format specified in the following table.

```
Start offset (in bytes) | Size (bytes) | Data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
                      0 |            4 | Header: Version Information
                      4 |            4 | Header: Flags
                      8 |            4 | Header: Number of Mappings
                     12 |            4 | Individual Mapping
                    ... |          ... | ...
           Last 4 bytes |            4 | Null Terminator (0x00000000)
```

> The first and second `DWORDS` store header information and should be set to all zeroes for the current version of the Scan Code Mapper. The third `DWORD` entry holds a count of the total number of mappings that follow, including the null terminating mapping. The minimum count would therefore be 1 (no mappings specified). The individual mappings follow the header. Each mapping is one `DWORD` in length and is divided into two `WORD` length fields. Each `WORD` field stores the scan code for a key to be mapped.
>
> <sub>Source: [Keyboard and mouse class drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx)</sub>

### Manual registry editing

1. Open a command prompt as administrator.
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t REG_BINARY /d 00000000000000000200000037e0640000000000 /f
   ```

   In this case there's only one mapping: the F13 key (scancode `0x0064`). It is remapped to `0xe037`, which is the Print Screen key.
3. Log off or restart Windows to apply the changes.

### Using SharpKeys

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows to remap one key to any other key. Included in the application is a list of common keyboard keys and a Type Key feature to automatically recognize most keyboard keys.

**Note** Latest version requires .NET Framework 4.x in order to work. You can get an [older version](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/releases/view/20569) if you need it to run with .NET Framework 2.0/3.x. A portable version is available too.

1. Download and run [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).
2. Click **Add**, select **Function: F13 (00_64)** from the list, and map it to **Special: PrtSc (E0_37)**, then click **OK**.
3. Click **Write to Registry**, then log off or restart Windows to apply the changes.

## Further reading

- [Scancode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode)
- [Keyboard and mouse class drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx)
- [Command Prompt: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7)
- [Using An Apple Keyboard With Windows 7](http://nullcandy.com/using-an-apple-keyboard-with-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can this not be achieved without additional software (as requested in OP)? I need to do this in my work environment where I ideally should not install additional software.

Comment: @2C-B I initially thought "additional software" actually meant additional, *running-all-the-time* software. SharpKeys is available as a portable version too, but you can also manually edit the registry (although it's not as comfy). See my updated answer.